# How to prevent inner div's event handler from executing in outer div's event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I have two `<div>`s, one inside the other, each has their own click handler, and i want the outer div's click handler to trigger first when user clicks. And inside the outer div's click handler, I want to conditionally check if I want to block the inner div's click handler from executing is that possible?

for example in react:

```
<div class="outer" onclick={outerHandler}>

<div class="inner onclick={innerHandler}>

Click Me!

<div>

</div>

const outerHandler = () => { console.log("alert outer"); if (something != something) { //block inner handler from executing}}

const innerHandler = () => {console.log("alert inner")};
```

Answer (score 2):

In the outer handler, handle the event in the capturing phase, and then you can call `stopPropagation` on the event if you want to prevent it from propagating downward to the inner element:

```
<div class="outer" onClickCapture={outerHandler}>
```

(note the use of `onClickCapture` - this is essential, it indicates that the event is handled in the capturing phase, not the bubbling phase)

And then, in `outerHandler`:

```
const outerHandler = (e) => {
  const stopInnerClick = true; // put your desired logic here
  if (stopInnerClick) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

Also note that `onClick` is case-sensitive (`onclick=` won't work), and you need a `"` to terminate the inner `class`)

Live snippet:

```js
const outerHandler = (e) => {
  const stopInnerClick = true; // put your desired logic here
  if (stopInnerClick) {
    console.log('Propagation stopped');
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
};
const innerHandler = () => {
  console.log('inner');
};

class Comp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="outer" onClickCapture={outerHandler}>outer
        <div class="inner" onClick={innerHandler}>inner
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Comp />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is a great answer! But it seems e.stopPropagation() doesn't work if the inner div's event hander is attached through jquery. What I am trying to do is to have logic in the outer div handler in react to stop some legacy code in jqery from executing in certain circumstances

Comment: That's a pretty strange situation, but if the handler really is attached to the inner element, `stopPropagation` will definitely work. If it doesn't, then the handler isn't attached to the inner element - post a [MCVE]?

Answer (score 0):

In React, you could change the state based on whatever condition you want, and then check the value in your handler.

```
const state = {
    blockInner: false
}

const outerHandler = () => { 
    console.log("alert outer"); 
    if (something !== something) {
        this.setState({ blockInner: true });
    }
}

const innerHandler = () => {
    if (!this.state.blockInner) {
        console.log("alert inner");
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work because `setState` is asynchronous - the inner handler will run before the state has changed. Setting state for something that only matters during the handling of the current event is quite overkill too.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Hrm perhaps I misunderstood the question. I don't think OP wants both handlers to execute when a div is clicked, but rather have some logic in one handler determine whether a later click on the second div should be handled or not. In this case, setState is perfect. However, after re-reading the question, I do see that I misunderstood.